# C binary file handling as an array

Tags: c, file, binary

I would like to access a file as you would an array, rather than use fopen() and  fgetc()/fputc() etc.

I'm looking for a method that will give me a pointer to the file which I can then treat as a big string(EOF terminated or a given length, whatever), I want the whole file in memory and need fast access to specific sections.

Is this possible? If so could you recommend a method? I'm also curious why this is not the default way of accessing files in c, is it because files are not generally stored in contiguous memory?

thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you can, in many environments, access a file in a "memory mapped" mode, allowing you to overlay it with any array or structure view you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for something called memory-mapped files. For example, if you're on Unix, look for [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html).

```
fd = open(...);    
p = mmap(NULL, buf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

/* Use `p` like a pointer to some memory and fstat to find size. */
```

If you're on Win32 look for [`CreateFileMapping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537) and [`MapViewOfFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761).

Comment: Thanks, I'm on Linux btw will look into it!

Comment: @sfi I added some details for `mmap`.

Comment: @cnicutar very nice. thanks. on the off chance some Windows engineer has a similar question and is lead here.